# Flex 4: Dynamically created DataGrid with custom ItemRender, problem detecting right cell

Tags: datagrid, flex4, itemrenderer

```
  <mx:DataGrid id="calendarGrid" 
               dataProvider="{rows}"
               width="100%" 
               height="100%">
    <mx:columns/>
  </mx:DataGrid>
```

I dynamically add columns and rows to it in this way:

```
    var dgc0:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn("timeSlot");
    dgc0.headerText="Hours";
    hoursColumns=new Array();
    hoursColumns.push(dgc0);

for (var i:int=7;i<21;i++)
{
   var dgc:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn();
   dgc.headerText=i+":00-"+(i+1)+":00";
   dgc.itemRenderer=new ClassFactory(CustomRenderer);
   hoursColumns.push(dgc);
}

calendarGrid.columns=slotsColumns; 

for(var i:int =0;i<maxNum+1;i++)
{
   rows.addItem({timeSlot:"Day n° "+(i+1)});
}
```

My CustomRenderer detects user clicks and changes the color of the selected cell.
When I select one cell on, say, the first column, it is colored but if I select another cell on the same column the first one is uncolored and the second isn't colored.
Maybe the same renderer is used for all cell in the column?
There's a way to avoid it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it!

Sorry my second unnecessary question :( my custom renderer constructor has this code inside:

```
addEventListener(FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE, resetCell);
```

which reset cell color, I've remove it and now seems work...
sorry again.